# Implementing components with react-native-web

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I use [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) to have components that can be used not only mobile but also in web browsers. My understanding of the idea is simple: Provide an HTML-based implementation for the regular react-native components.

If I understand the library correct, it works by overwriting the package with webpack:

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
    ...
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'react-native': 'react-native-web'
        }
    }
};
```

But what if I want to provide implementations for components that are not implemented by react-native-web? And how could I provide an implementation for external packages like [react-native-button](https://github.com/ide/react-native-button).

Answer (score 0):

A package like `react-native-button` is just a collection of code that uses React Native's API. If you load `react-native-web` as a stand-in for the original implementation, the third-party package *might* "just work". How well it works depends on how complete `react-native-web`'s implementation of the API is.

Note that some third-party React Native packages include specific non-Javascript code (iOS/Android native code) that `react-native-web` does not aim to implement. If the package documentation says that you need to run `react-native link` or change your Xcode/Android Studio project configuration, it's probably not readily usable with `react-native-web`.